# Opening the about: links used specifically for Firefox from File explorer

Tags: firefox, windows-explorer, autohotkey

Help with opening the `about:` links used specifically for Firefox. More info [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/The_about_protocol)

I am trying to open them from File explorer. I tried dragging `about:addons` URL from Firefox Adrress bar to Explorer. when I double click to open them, old Internet explorer opens with an error, even though Firefox is my defauly browser.

How do I Save these `about:addons` links correctly so I can open then in Firefox via File explorer

I plan on integrating them into my scripting language of choice, Autohotkey.
The below exmple is where I am stuck

```
a::
Run, C:\Users\....\Documents\Add-ons Manager.URL
Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a desktop shortcut (.lnk) that opens to an *About:* page, create a new desktop shortcut, or copy the existing shortcut, to Firefox, and append a space and the *About:* page to which you want to link. For example, to open *about:config*, create the following shortcut.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" about:config
```

Of course, if Firefox is in the 64-bit *Program Files* folder, modify accordingly.

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" about:config
```

Take a look at *about:about* for many other configuration and information pages.

Comment: Thank you so much for this and for the about:about point as well. your solution was just what I needed to stop mucking about in the dark

Comment: Glad it helped... actually, I found it by experimentation, because this is *not* well documented, AFAIK.